# Popover content not showing after couple of clicks

Tags: javascript, html, popover

I was having problem debugging this issue where the popover content shows for the first two clicks

[First two clicks result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Zkc.png)

The content won't show again everytime I click again.

[After two clicks result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQAMe.png)

I have tried these solutions.They work the same but none of them solve my issue.

first solution

```
function popoverdisplaypayments(booking_id,poptable){
        $('#popoverpayments'+booking_id).popover({
         html: true,
         container:'body',
         placement: 'top',
     });
     var popover = $('#popoverpayments'+booking_id).data('bs.popover');
     popover.options.content = $('#myPopoverContent').html(poptable);
     $('#popoverpayments'+booking_id).popover('show');
```

second solution

```
function popoverdisplaypayments(booking_id,poptable){
        $('#popoverpayments'+booking_id).popover({
         html: true,
         container:'body',
         placement: 'top',
         content: function () {
                return $('#myPopoverContent').html(poptable);
         }
     });
     $('#popoverpayments'+booking_id).popover('show');
```

third solution

```
setTimeout(function () {
    function popoverdisplaypayments(booking_id,poptable){
            $('#popoverpayments'+booking_id).popover({
             html: true,
             container:'body',
             placement: 'top',
             content: function () {
                    return $('#myPopoverContent').html(poptable);
             }
         });
         $('#popoverpayments'+booking_id).popover('show'); 
},500);
```

It seems like the content is not replaced in the popover option.Anyone knows the problem?

Comment: can you put up a jsfiddle or something??

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp div in javascript and append in document body as shown in example , call it on body onload this will popup a alert message to the user

http://smartsnipp.ecomparefiles.com/code/asp_net_web_application/how_to_detect_adblock_javascript_example.aspx